# Empathy Facebook Stopped Working,No Account Settings

Tags: 14.04, empathy, facebook

I had to do a ctrl-alt-f1 log out,because I was stuck between workspaces(ugh),When I rebooted I forgot to add "noapic" to my cmd line to fix MP-BIOS I/O Timer Bug(ugh),the system boots with or without it,but I've always used it to be safe.
When I clicked to open Empathy it said "You Need To Set Up An Account To See Contacts Here",when I had already setup my FB/Empathy account in System Settings.
Clicking the Account Settings button does nothing,and in System Settings the Empathy on/off slider is missing from my list.
I have already done a purge uninstall and reinstall of Empathy,but this has literally changed nothing.
Empathy is one of my favorite things about Ubuntu,and no I have not yet tried Pidgin,because I thoroughly enjoy Empathy.
Someone PLEASE help me.
My system is an HP Media Server AMD Athlon64x2 with 2 GB DDR2,Using Nvidia 304 Proprietary Drivers.Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.
Let me know anyting else I can provide.

Comment: Can't understand your problem description as is it written now, but notice than after April 30 2015 the XMPP API that allows desktop messaging clients to login to, send and receive messages from Facebook is being turned off. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/facebook-chat-api-empathy-pidgin-stop-working

Comment: It's currently May,and it worked until today,so that doesn't seem to  be a problem.I have it working right now through Pidgin,but I still preffer Empathy.

Comment: Have you tested any other XMPP client works with your facebook account? It works on Pidgin for me too, but I have the account configured since 2009, maybe the API will be shutted down later and just doesn't allow new clients.

Comment: It works with Pidgin perfectly.But like I said it was strange,I'd been using it with Empathy for about a week and a half,I rebooted,and went to sign in and it said I had no account configured.But when I went to the Ubuntu account settings there used to an Empathy slider listed under the Facebook Account,along with Shotwell and a Photo Search Plugin.The Empathy slider has dissappeared the other two are still there.It's strange,It seems like its a Ubuntu problem.